# ngAnimate in Rails, I just want to hook it up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ng-animate

why is it always so hard to hook things up to AngularJS?!?!?!

here's the error I get for anything new I try to install to Angularjs:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24asyncCallbackProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24asyncCallback%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile

Everything works fine when I don't include ngAnimate in:

```
WriterSarah = angular.module("WriterSarah", ["restangular", "ui.router", "ngAnimate" ])
```

I put my angular-animate.min.js file  in the SAME place that I do all my other Angularjs files, and I required it in my Application.js file in the SAME way that I did for restangular and ui.router

I restarted my server a bunch of times as well.  what am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure you included angular-animate.js file after the angular.js file and that your script tags are not self-closing?

Comment: yes and yes.  I can see that GET angular-animate.min.js  is there with a 200 ok message in my Net tab of firebug

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that the Angular version does not match to the angular-animate version. Check to see if the angular versions are the same between both files.

Comment: you were right.  I know have the same versions for angular.min.js and angular-animate.js .      my error message is slightly different at least:  Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24animateProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24animateProvider F/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:7:442 $b/l.$injector<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:33:127 c@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.min.js?body=1:31:176  ETC ETC ETC

Comment: Try including the unminified versions of angular. The errors will be more informative.

Comment: ahh... that helped.  somewhere along the way I stuck $animateProvider in my controller... and using angular.js had a more clear error message.  I think the real fix was actually getting the right angular-animate version that matched with my angular version... from then on it was just this $animateProvider throwing me off.  Thanks!!!  Thanks!! Thanks!!!